# AMD driver does not work on kernel 3.19.0-26

Tags: kernel, ati, fglrx

I am asking for a help or a fix for this black screen in Ubuntu 15.04.

The black screen contains the message `starting version 219` and I am stuck in there for like a day already. Been trying to find a fix in Google but failed. So far I tried fixing it by going into the terminal using commands like:

```
sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f
```

This command dint go through, because I don't have `sddm` in my system, so it failed. Next thing is, I found out, that my `sddm` was a `lightdm`, so I tried using

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service -f
```

…and same result, but this time, it got a message, that it is not meant to be activated through `systemctl`. Lastly I tried this one:

```
systemctl start lightdm
```

This goes in. After putting my password, it went through, but it went back to the black screen. Tried hitting the shift key, when I rebooted it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have an AMD graphics?

Comment: Yes sir! My graphics driver is amd radeon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Ubuntu bug resulting in an incompatibility between kernel 3.19.0-26 and the `fglrx-updates` package.

You can boot with the previous 3.19.0-25 kernel using `grub`.

This bug has been fixed already, but the new package did not reach the stable repository yet. It is released today and will reach main server today. Local mirrors may be updated a bit later.

You can download and install the patched package for 15.04 now from [HERE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/2:15.200-0ubuntu4.2)

[BugLink](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1479913)

To fix it now press Ctrl+Alt+F1 when you get stuck on black screen.
Then log into the console and run there:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic
sudo reboot
```

But after you see `fglrx-updates` package is updated, you will need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

to restore the meta package to get kernels updated.

For Ubuntu 14.04.3 run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

instead of the previous command.

**Update** Now this issue is completely resolved in repositories.

Comment: thanks for this sir but im sorry. I am a complete noob when it comes to this.. Can you teach me how to install these? Or how to put this as a fix to the problem? Thank you so much

Comment: Press Shift when you boot, get into grub menu and select previous kernel. Then download and install that deb pacakage, then reboot.

Comment: I am trying to do that but it doesnt work. I dont know. After reboot i am pressing the shift but it just go to black screen

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: ok i see it.. after that? how will I install the fix?

Comment: Just do not upgrade kernel till `fglrx-updates` does not appear in updates. The fix will come by itself. The system will work without the fix on the previous kernel.

Comment: Ok. The first fix you have suggested is done and it worked like a charm! The only thing is that there is an error prompt in the desktop saying about xorg problem.. And by any chance this fglrx-updates will be seen in settings>updates?

Comment: The error will appear only once. It will be seen not in settings but in updates application.